# How to get pull requests references for an issue

Tags: github, github-api

Given a GitHub issue, is there any way to get the pull requests that reference to that issue via API?

That info is showed in the GitHub html page but I can't see nothing in the API documentation.

Is it really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to get the pull requests that reference to that issue via API

Not directly.
Even the [reverse is not possible](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/), as a pull request has a link '`issue`' pointing to... itself.

But as mentioned in [the issue API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue):

> In the past, pull requests and issues were more closely aligned than they are now.
>   **As far as the API is concerned, every pull request is an issue, but not every issue is a pull request**.
>
> This endpoint may also return `pull requests` in the response. If an issue is a pull request, the object will include a pull_request key.

So you would need to list the comments of a pull request (using the [Issue Comments API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/) since comments on PR are done with it), and parse said comment to find a reference to an issue.

Comment: Well, the `issue` link is a link to itself since a pull request its considered a kind of issue so I'd say that the reverse it's only possible parsing the `body` field too (I've done it yet).

Comment: @IvanGuardado I agree. parsing the body content seems the only way to find pull request references from an issue.

Comment: If you edit the answer to avoid confusing other people about that, I'll accept it as answer :)

Comment: @IvanGuardado Sorry, I didn't spot the broken link immediately. I have fixed said link and edited the answer.

Comment: I meant the sentence "The reverse is possible, as a pull request has a link 'issue' pointing to the issue location." because is not true

Comment: @IvanGuardado isn't it what https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#link-relations shows?

Comment: @IvanGuardado I see what you mean, looking at the output of https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request: issue refers to the PR itself. Got it. I have edited the answer.